# Trim start of NSString ( TrimStart(string) in Objective C )

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, nsstring, trim

I'm looking for the [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) equivalent to the C# method `TrimStart(string)`.

Something like:

```
- (NSString*)trimStart:(NSString*)inputString withTrimString:(NSString*)trimChars {
    return inputString;
}
```

but where

```
[self trimStart:@"333test1233" withTrimString:@"3"];
```

returns test1233

And is not just trimming all 3's from the string.

Comment: The `TrimStart` method trims from the **start** of the string.  Which your example does.  What is the problem?

Comment: @Matthew, I don't think the method "trimStart" exists in Cocoa. It is a method the OP wants, but doesn't have.

Comment: My bad, I read the question as "here is the output of my method, why is it broken"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation NSString (Trimming)

-(NSString*)trimCharactersFromStart:(NSString*)characters
{
    NSCharacterSet* set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:characters] invertedSet];
    NSRange         range = [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set];

    if(range.location == NSNotFound)
        return @"";
    else if(range.location != 0)
        return [self substringFromIndex:range.location];
    else
        return self;
}

@end
```

Note that if you were trying to trim the characters from the start and end of the string you could just use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

Comment: This does not work for the OPs sample problem where the string starts with repeats of the character to be skipped.

Comment: Fixed this answer to use an inverted character set so it actually works :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using -rangeOfCharacterFromSet with the NSAnchoredSearch option. 
Then use the result of this in a call to -substringFromIndex to remove the chars at the start of the string.

Comment: RangeOfCharacterFromSet will return a range for the first occurrence of a character in the set. If the OP wants to skip a block of repeating characters (3s in this case) your solution won't work.

Comment: @DuncanC That's the purpose of NSAnchoredSearch, it will only match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Ok, but it seems to me it still won't work. It will find the first occurrence of any character from the specified set. If you want to skip multiple occurrences of a character (like the OPs "333test1233" sample) it will return the index of the first occurrence of a 3, at index 0, right?

Comment: It returns a range, so it will return a length of 3 at an index of 0.  NSAnchoredSearch insures that the index is either 0 or NSNotFound.

Comment: @David, no, it does not. I just tried it. It returns a 1-character range for the first character from the specified set that it finds.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString*)trimStart:(NSString*)inputString withTrimString:(NSString*)trimChars 
{
    NSString *buffer = inputString;
    NSInteger i = 0;
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet charactersSetWithCharactersInString:trimChars];    

    while ((i<[buffer length])&&[charSet characterIsMember:[buffer characetrAtIndex:i])
    {
      i ++;
    }

 return [buffer substringFromIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: Why create the `NSCharacterSet` over and over? Just create it once at the start. Also, this will fail if `trimChars` contain any characters with a Unicode value of `\U10000` or higher which includes many Emoji characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
+ (NSString*)trimStart:(NSString*)inputString withTrimString:(NSString*)trimChars {
    NSCharacterSet* trimSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:trimChars];
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [inputString length]; i++) {
        if (![trimSet characterIsMember:[inputString characterAtIndex:i]]) {
            return [inputString substringFromIndex:i];
        }
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the closest thing in the Cocoa string libraries is the string method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` However, that method will trim characters from both the beginning and the end.

You might need to write your own trimStart method. It wouldn't be that hard. Something like this:

```
 -(NSString *)trimCharacter: (unichar) charToTrim fromStartOfString: (NSString *) string
 {
     NSUIndex index = 0;
     if ([string length] == 0)
         return nil;
     unichar thisChar = [string characterAtIndex: index];
     while (thisChar == charToTrim) do
     {
         thisChar = [string characterAtIndex: index++];
     }
     return [string substringFromIndex: index];
 }
```

Note that some people are suggesting using `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:`, with an options value of NSAnchoredSearch.

This does not work. The following code:

```
NSCharacterSet *theSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"3"];

NSString *stringToTrim = @"333test1233";

NSRange range = [stringToTrim rangeOfCharacterFromSet: theSet options: NSAnchoredSearch];

NSLog(@"Range.location = %d, range.length = %d", range.location, range.length);
```

Returns

> Range.location = 0, range.length = 1

Which is not what you want. You want to find the range of ALL the characters to skip.